# GEOTOOLS - FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore() on jar

Tags: geotools

The following code works fine on my Eclipse IDE.

```
private void getLayersAndDisplay() throws Exception {
        URL imageURL = ImageLab.class.getResource("earthlights.jpg");
        File imageFile = new File(imageURL.toURI());
        URL shapeFileURL = ImageLab.class.getResource("countries.shp");
        File shapeFile = new File(shapeFileURL.toURI());
        URL shapeFileURL2 = ImageLab.class.getResource("Brasil.shp");
        File shapeFile2 = new File(shapeFileURL2.toURI());
        displayLayers(imageFile, shapeFile,shapeFile2);
    }
```

However, I need to compile this to a jar File. A jar doesn't accept the creation of a new File on its content. The problem is, that in the function displayLayers, the FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore() only accepts File types to work on. Also, I think this part of the code would give me some troubles too:

```
AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat( rasterFile ); 
Hints hints = new Hints();
if (format instanceof GeoTiffFormat) {
    hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
}
reader = format.getReader(rasterFile, hints);
```

Is there any possible solution to that?

Comment: Use URL and DatastoreFinder? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to read a shapefile directly from my program (without showing a dialog box to the user select a shapefile, but instead, loading it directly on my class). I need to generate a runnable jar for testing purposes, to execute my app outside my IDE. However, a jar file doesn't allow me to use File file = new File("shape.shp") but instead an getResourceStream(). DataStoreFInder.getDataStore however, only receives a File object as a parameter.

Comment: This question does not appear to be GIS-centric. You might find a faster result by asking in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure if you will have a file or an URL as input then you should use the standard `DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(...)` method which takes a `Map` of parameters and use the Java SPI mechanism to load all the available `DataStores` and checks to see which of them can handle that set of parameters.

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("URL",url);
DataStore ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
```

However if you are specifically writing a test case then you would probably be better off using the GeoTools [`TestData` class](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/test/TestData.html) which gives you access to `File` and `URL` references to objects in the test resources directory. There is a longer discussion of its uses in the [developers' guide](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/conventions/test/data.html).